# How do I make a Multiplayer game Server?

Tags: c#, xna

I want a to create a multiplayer game and use my computer as the server. I'm fairly experience with C# and the XNA environment but I'm not quite sure how to set up my computer to work as a server and how to make the client (game) use that server.

Can anyone help me with that please?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[XNA Game Studio 3.1: Tutorial 5: Adding Multiplayer and Networking Support to the Game](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb975645%28v=xnagamestudio.31%29.aspx)

Full on tutorial for adding multiplayer support. This goes along with the Asteroid style starter kit / tutorial on MSDN, but given that you already have XNA and C# experience, you should be able to pick through what you need.

Remember that without releasing a dedicated multiplayer server application, you're in the scenario where either of the clients could be the host. Not an issue, given that you'll be implementing both client and server in the game anyway, but architecturally worth thinking about.

Comment: Please be aware that Microsoft no longer except XNA 3.1 submissions if you are thinking on publishing your game.